# Mobile application how to prevent the confirm box is not closed when i clicked outside this dialog

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

Can you please explain how we will use the code below because we do not have a dialog:

```
var message = text;
var title = "INFO";
var buttonLabels = "OK";
navigator.notification.confirm(message, null, title, buttonLabels);
```

Can somebody explains in mobile application how to get the above dialog to close when i clicked outside this dialog?

It's only closed when i clicked on OK button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(Your Title)
            .setMessage(Your Message)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Action to be performed on click  `
            }

        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", null)//Keep If you want to
        .show();
```

Try This..